# IntelliJ IDEA remote development code "cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

In remote machine, after build a JAVA project in IDEA, IDEA can find all code declaration and use ctrl+click to jump.

[Sample in remote machine with IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYhYG.png)(use impication to show idea can find relation with this code)

However, in local machine, use remote development, open same project(been built in remote IDEA), local Idea can only jump simple code, can not find all code declaration

[Sample in local IDEA with remote development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8S8w.png)

Is there any way to find all code declatation in local machine? or use build result in remote IDEA.

remote environment: ubuntu
local environment: windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using local JDK while in a local project. Based on the image, it seems like IntelliJ IDEA didn't recognise Java files.

Comment: I think it's not related to local JDK. In local machine, use IDEA for local project, I can get all declaration. However, If I use IDEA in windows to remote dev my code In remote machine, It cannot find declaration... How can I use remote JDK to interpreter my remote code in local machine?